# Question closed because website surprisingly does not have particular feature

Tags: discussion, scope

Not mine, but I wonder why this question has been closed:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45582

1. It could perfectly be the case that there is a trick to solve the
   problem, by clicking here and here. That would make a perfect
   question+answer.
2. If there is no such trick, just answer "there is no such feature yet"

The asker doesn't know in advance whether it will be (1) or (2), so it is a case of "Could have been a great question, but it happens that website has not implemented that particular feature yet, so let me downvote your question".

I think such questions should be reopened and answered "there is no such feature yet".
Or am I missing a policy that says otherwise? If yes, I would appreciate a specific URL.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a situation of both not having a registered or stable account (which they would be able to then track answers and comments with on the question) and being an issue that appears to require a certain urgency or level of escalation up the Facebook Support chain.

Ordinarily, yes, this question would be okay, and the answers you posited would fit.

But in this case, where the account just no longer exists (or did not exist in the first place as most anonymous users do not follow their question when migrated) any help would be missed, and dealing with a possibly serious situation of harassment that needed to go through the official channels of support instead, as a comment on the question pointed out.

Comment: yep, the last paragraph is exactly why I closed it.